# Area differential substitution

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I've been reading the proof of the mean-value formulas for Laplace's equation and here is my question:

Suppose that $\alpha(n)$ denotes the volume of an unitary $n$-ball. In the problem says that
$$\frac{1}{n\alpha(n)r^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B(x,r)}{u(y)dS(y)}=\frac{1}{n\alpha(n)}\int_{\partial B(0,1)}{u(x+rz)dS(z)},$$ for $u\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$, under good conditions.
How do I prove that
$$dS(y)=r^{n-1}dS(z).$$
If you could leave some references, I might thank you.

Comment: How does surface area scale when you dilate the unit ball/sphere to that of radius $r$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Well, if we see from this perspective then it is trivial. But generally how it could change?

Comment: In general, you compute the Jacobian determinant of the transformation. This is the change of variables theorem and only when that is a constant function can you pull it out of the integral.